# Integral of Lorentzian yields different results depending on when parameter assigments are made

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, assignment

I'm evaluating the integral of a Lorentzian, which I know equals one. First I define the function and evaluate the integral in two slightly different ways. Surprisingly, I do not get the right answer when I do symbolic integration first.

```
g[x_] := (a/(2*\[Pi]))/((x - x0)^2 + (a/2)^2);

Integrate[g[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] /. {x0 -> 10} /. {a -> 4}
```

> Undefined

```
Integrate[g[x] /. {x0 -> 10} /. {a -> 4}, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> 1

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 3):

Clearly It is a bug in Integrate.

```
g = (a/(2*\[Pi]))/((x - x0)^2 + (a/2)^2);
Integrate[g, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now do the indefinite integration

```
   int0 = Integrate[g, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
   % /. {x0 -> 10} /. {a -> 4}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  (% /. x -> Infinity) - (% /. x -> -Infinity)
  (* 1 *)
```

I tried to do Full Trace to see if a clue might show up to tell one where and why, but hard to read. Wait and see what others say. But my vote is for a bug.

Fyi, Maple17 seems to do it ok both in definite and indefinite case here. Notice how the `x0` does even show up in the definite integration. It cancels out ! Only `a` shows up.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It might be one of those cases where a branch cut went wrong problems.

Comment: I found a bug! :)